# Recursive functions: can someone explain how this code printed 1 to 5?

Tags: python, recursion

```py
def recursion_1(n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    recursion_1 (n-1)
    print(n)
```

I don't understand how this code printed 1 to 5 the same way a for loop would have printed a list of range from 1 to 5.
Passing 5 as the argument here.

Comment: You're calling it as `recursion_1(5)`, right? Please [edit] and include that in the question, for completeness. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: What do you know about recursion already? What do you understand about how the function works? SO is not meant to provide tutorials, but if you have a specific sticking point, we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to understand it is probably to imagine how it would look if you replaced the function calls with its definition.

So `recursion_1(5)` becomes :

```
if 5 == 0:
    return
recursion_1 (4)
print(5)
```

Which in turn is equivalent to :

```
if 5 == 0:
    return
if 4 == 0:
    return
recursion_1 (4)
print(4)
print(5)
```

Et cetera until :

```
if 5 == 0:
    return
if 4 == 0:
    return
if 3 == 0:
    return
if 2 == 0:
    return
if 1 == 0:
    return
recursion_1 (0)
print(1)
print(2)
print(3)
print(4)
print(5)
```

Then `recursion_1(0)` will return because the condition is met (`0 == 0` is true) and each precedent call will return after printing its number.